# lvm snapshot: how to get a list of changed, added, deleted files?

Tags: linux, filesystems, lvm

i have an lvm snapshot and i would like to see what files have been **changed, added or deleted**. (Just the file list is sufficient.)

Is there an easy way to get the list?

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Mount the old snapshot read-only `mount /dev/snapshot-somewhere /snap`
2. Make lists of the files on real fs and snapshot `cd /snap; ls -lR . >/tmp/list.snap` (or use mtree or rsync to make the list)
3. Compare the lists `diff -u list.real list.snap`

rsync can make a file list when called with just one argument:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ rsync -r .
drwxrwxrwt         612 2012/01/19 10:43:15 .
-rwxr-xr-x        9444 2012/01/19 08:43:13 foo
```

mtree can make a file which it can check for changes against life filesystem:

```
$ cd /tmp/tree
$ mtree -c > /tmp/list.mtree
$ touch bar.c
$ echo '/* comment */' >> foo.c
$ mtree < /tmp/list.mtree
$ mtree < /tmp/desc 
. changed
    modification time expected Thu Jan 19 11:18:11 2012 found Thu Jan 19 11:20:46 2012
bar.c extra
foo.c changed
    size expected 1350 found 1364
    modification time expected Thu Jan 19 11:18:11 2012 found Thu Jan 19 11:21:26 2012
```

Comment: that was something i was thinking of, but isn't there a faster and maybe more sophisticated solution? can't we directly ask LVM?

Comment: @JMW LVM is a pure volume manager that hosts binary chunks which you may format to any file system you like. LVM doesn't know about files at all. There are filesystems that have their snapshots though.

Comment: And there is ZFS that does both volume management and filesystem stuff :)

Comment: ok, good to know, that there is no faster method.